# Control visibility of division based on if condition in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

In my visual-force page i have few div elements clubbed in one division. I want to control visibility of each of these sub-divisions using if condition.
i.e. IF value of {!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_1__c}  is not Null then show first sub div.
IF value of {!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_2__c} is not Null then show Second sub div.....and so on.

My page

```
<div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 1:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_1__c}</div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 2:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_2__c}</div>                   
        <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 3:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_3__c}</div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 4:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_4__c}</div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 5:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_5__c}</div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 6:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_6__c}</div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 7:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_7__c}</div>
</div>
```

I have tried to add if condition in style attribute of Div element as suggested at this forum : http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-check-if-condition-in-salesforce.html

```
<div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
                <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%;{!IF(({!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_1__c}!=null),'','display:none')}"><b>Program Preference 1:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_1__c}</div>
                <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 2:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_2__c}</div>                   
                <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 3:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_3__c}</div>
                <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 4:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_4__c}</div>
                <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 5:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_5__c}</div>
                <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 6:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_6__c}</div>
                <div style="margin-bottom:2%;Float:left;width:50%"><b>Program Preference 7:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!mapOfPaymentRecord['StudentDetails'].nm_Lead__r.Program_Preference_7__c}</div>
            </div>
```

But no luck...it says syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the merge syntax again once you are already in a merge.

**Incorrect**

```
{!IF({!condition}, truthy_value, falsy_value}
```

**Correct**

```
{!IF(condition, truthy_value, falsy_value)}
```